# Difference AC signal and small signal / DC Signal and Operation Point

Tags: ac, dc, small-signal, signal-theory

What is exactly the difference between an ac signal and a small signal? Or analogue between a dc signal and operation point.

I've understood ac signal as a signal with a frequency > 0 Hz and dc as a signal with a frequency of 0 Hz but after research (as well here) I'm still confused. I even found definitions that describe DC only as a uni polar signal and ac as only polarity changing (regardless of frequency perspective). It looks like the exact definition depends on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AC signal is any signal which is alternating around zero. A DC signal is a signal who is not AC, whose flow is unidirectional. An operating point represents the solution to a circuit at a given time, represented in the voltages and the currents of the consituent elements. A small signal is a concept in analyzing a circuit's AC response by linearizing the circuit around its operating point and determining the response of the system to an infinitesimal AC signal, as if it were linear; it measures the dynamics of the system through simplification.

A 1 Vpk sine with a 2 Vdc offset would be a DC signal, overall, since the alternating part does not go below zero (e.g. the current flows in one direction, at all times). The same 1 Vpk signal with 0.5 Vdc offset will be an AC signal because there is a time when the direction of the current in inversed.

Take, for example, the following circuit:

[image: AC, DC, op pnt]

`V(in)` is an AC signal because it alternates around zero, even if less negative than positive. `V(out)` is a DC signal because at no times it goes below zero. The green numbers are the operating point as calculated by the solver (the floating one is the current through the diode).

[image: small signal]

And this is the small signal response of the system. Notice that the source now has a parameter, `{DC}`, representing the DC voltage at `time=0` for `V1`. This is used with a `.STEP` command that alternates its value between `0 V` (blue trace) and `1 V` (red). Ignore the green labels for now, they can only display one value at a time, and the one that you see is the operating point calculated for `DC=0`; for `DC=1` you would have seen the same values as in the first picture.

What you see are two traces, which represent the response of the system, linearized at the calculated operating point. The blue trace is for `DC=0`, which means the diode is not polarized, therefore not conducting. As a consequence, its resistance is very large and, combined with the 1 kΩ load, it acts as a resistive divider causing an ≈-85 dB response.

With `DC=1`, its resistance is minimal and acts as a short, therefore the response (red trace) is that of a 1st order circuit. You can also see that the phase starts rising towards the end, hinting of a zero nearby, but off scale: that's the junction capacitance.

So, for both cases, the response was given by replacing the diode (a nonlinear element) with its equivalent linear representation, passive elements and linear sources (controlled or not). And it represents the dynamics of the system because it uses a small signal around an operating point on the slope of the transfer function, or a derivative, and derivatives are used to measure dynamics.

It's for this reason that opamp analyses showing 100+ dB response look very unrealistic, until you realize that it's not a *large* signal analysis, it's just a response meant to be analyzed as the dynamics of the system -- or how it *would* respond *if* it were linear around a certain point.